# Junit test for nifi processor which extends abstract class

Tags: junit, mockito, connection-pooling, apache-nifi

how to write Junit test for nifi processor which extends abstract class

```
public class myProcessor extends AbstractDatabaseFetchProcessor {

@Override
public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSessionFactory sessionFactory)
        throws ProcessException {

}
```

Where the database connection is created from the connection pool DBCPService and some PropertyDescriptors are fetching from the abstract class AbstractDatabaseFetchProcessor.

Im using TestRunner from apache nifi.I would like to mock the database connection and would like to know how to set the controllerService(for connection) as testRunner property.

I'm new to nifi, Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

see the tests for standard processors

- [DBCPServiceSimpleImpl class](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/DBCPServiceSimpleImpl.java)
- @Before [create DBCPServiceSimpleImpl register dbcp service in your runner under some name, enable it, and link processor runner with service by name](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/QueryDatabaseTableTest.java#L109)